# Unknown custom element:did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The following code is working on development but not on production , am getting error
I have added the name attribute on the componenet but it's still not working. For now i have removed the spinner component.

```
  Unknown custom element: <event-image> - did you register the component correctly? 
  For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option
```

my .vue component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div class="text-grey-darker text-center bg-grey-light mx-2 my-2 border border-teal 
 w-64 h-64 z-0 relative">                   
        <img :src="url" class="w-full h-full">
        <div class="pin-r pin-t absolute z-40">
            <button class="bg-transparent text-red bold text-xl italic" 
 @click="remove">X</button>
        </div>

    </div>      
 </template>

 <script>

export default{
    name:'event-image',

    props: ['image'],

    data(){

        return {
            showspinner:false
        }
    },

    methods: {
        remove(){
            this.showspinner = true;
            axios.delete('/media/'+JSON.parse(this.image).id)
                  .then(response => {
                    this.showspinner = false;
                    location.reload();
                  })
                  .catch(errors =>{

                  });
        }

    },

    computed : {
        url(){
            return JSON.parse(this.image).url;
        }
    }
   }

  </script>
```

and registered it on app.js as:

```
 Vue.component(
'event-image',
require('./components/event/EventImage.vue'));
```

then used it on blade like:

```
  @foreach($images as $image)
                 <event-image image="{{ json_encode($image) }}" ></event-image>   
 @endforeach
```

where is the error above comming from.

Comment: Why are you mixing blade with vue lol

Comment: @Phiter No problem in that.

Comment: Your code should work. Maybe you would show more, like full `app.js`

Comment: Did you debug the require ? Is it realy your component ?

Comment: The problem was the spinner ......

Answer (score 1):

Answering this question even though the original author determined a different reason for the problem: I received the same Vue error message and I'm guessing others will navigate here as well.

This fixed it for me when I added this line to my export statement:

```
    name: "Comment"
```

Note that "Comment" is the name of the (current) component that is recursively calling itself.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same err message using SFC ([Single file components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html)) with code like this:

Component I want to use in another one `./buttons/SomeButton.vue`:

```js
<template>
    ...html of component...
</template>

<script>

export default {
    name: "some-button",
    ...
}
</script>
```

Component which use that one above `./RowOfButtons.vue`:

```js
<template>
  <p>
    <some-button/>
  </p>
<template>
<script>
import SomeButton from "./buttons/SomeButton"

export default {
  name: "row-of-buttons",
    comments: {
        SomeButton
    },
    ...
}
</script>
```

And obviously there were typo due to PhpStorm completed it with `comments` instead of `components`.